# PHP: Radio button checked

Tags: php, radio-button, checked

I have two radiobutton, "A" and "B". When I checked the "A", then click the submit button after it load the "A" is already checked in the next form. Same also in "B". How can I code the radiobutton to remain checked when the user checked the radiobutton.

Here's my code where I want to insert the checked radiobutton.

```
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldNetname FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldNetname ORDER BY fldNetname");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio))
{                                           
    echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldNetname'] . "'>";
    echo $row['fldNetname'];"</div>";
}
```

*NOTE:

All I want is to remain the radio button checked...

Comment: You can't have two checkboxes with the same name checked at the same time, this is a HTML behavior, not PHP.

Comment: @DanyCaissy..Sorry I didn't clear my question... All I want is how to remain the radiobutton checked

Comment: If you want it to be checked, you add "checked" inside the input.

Comment: @DanyCaissy..not working..

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldNetname']."'  .<?php if ($_POST['playRadio[]'] == $row['fldNetname']) echo 'checked';. >";
```

Comment: I have an error.. when i put that code..syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Comment: @JackHarkness,...still the same...I already copy and paste it

Comment: there was extra ";". try this: echo "<div><input type='radio' name='playRadio' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldNetname']."' " .($_POST['playRadio'] == $row['fldNetname'] ? 'checked' : '') . " >";

Comment: @drull...its already okay..but the data from database didn't display